# How to read out a maven project creation timestamp directly in the java source code?

Tags: java, maven

I have created a possible solution to read out a timestamp, which was created by using Apache Maven, if I build this project as a JAR file (with the maven assembly plugin). But this solution works not fine and I don´t understand the reasons.

Here is the property "myMavenConstants.properties" file:

```
version=${project.version}
groupId=${project.groupId}
artifactId=${project.artifactId}
buildTime=${timestamp}
```

Here is the declared profile from my "pom.xml" file:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>m2e</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>m2e.version</name>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <maven.build.timestamp/>  
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Here is my Java class, which read out the property file:

```
public static class MyClass {

    private static Properties properties = myClass.createMetaInfo();

    protected static Properties createMetaInfo(){     

        InputStream resourceStream = null;
        Properties properties = new Properties();

        try {
            resourceStream =
                MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/myMavenConstants.properties");
            properties.load(resourceStream);
        } catch(IOException e){
            // Do something
        } finally{
            resourceStream.close();
        }
        return properties;
     }

     public static String getProperty(String s){
        return properties.getProperty(s);
     }
}
```

Here is the Java Interface, which I would like to read out the project build time:

```
public interface Constants {    

    public static final String VERSION = MyClass.getProperty(PROJECT_VERSION);
    public static final String VERSION_BUILD = 
                MyClass.getProperty(PROJECT_CREATE_TIME);
}
```

The value for VERSION was set correctly, but the value for VERSION_BUILD is already "${timestamp}". I have tried to build the maven project with eclipse plugin in Eclipse IDE and on the command line (with the command "mvn clean install").

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Another IMO cleaner way of doing this is via the manifest file: http://maven.apache.org/plugin-developers/cookbook/add-build-time-to-manifest.html

Comment: sorry but i need the maven assembly plugin. this is absoluty necessary

Comment: We can still create a manifest file with the maven-assembly-plugin: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/usage.html#Advanced_Configuration